# Room name is not assigned correctly in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Upon a button being pressed client-side, a `socket.emit` is called with the parameter being defined by an input box. Here's the server-side `socket.on`:

```
socket.on('createRoom', function(roomName) {
  socket.join('Room 1');
  console.log(io.sockets.adapter);
  console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
  let clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['Room 1'].sockets;
  console.log('A user joined the room with the name: ' + roomName + ". The user's name is " + raceResponse.user_name);
  console.log(clients);
  socket.emit('roomCreated', clients);
});
```

I have since changed this to have the room name defined server-side, as I was getting an error:

> `let clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['Room 1'].sockets;`
>   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined`

But notice the lines above it: they log `io.sockets.adapter` and `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`. I believe the latter is a list of all rooms, because it gives me:

> `{ ZJ81Hw0FkCIQxg86AAAA: [],
>     UoE9k4lTnGMUB9y6AAAB: [],
>     'Y-Tr2j9MxCzZokSSAAAC': [ 'Y-Tr2j9MxCzZokSSAAAC': true ]
>   }`

What this looks like to me is that the first item in the object is the default room, and the other item is the room that was just created, which has one user in. What's confusing me is that the room is not called 'Room 1', which is what I would expect it to be.

I may have completely misinterpreted what `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` means, so if that is the case please let me know.

`io.sockets.adapter` gives me:

```
Adapter {
  nsp: Namespace {
    name: '/',
    server: Server {
      nsps: [Object],
      _path: '/socket.io',
      _serveClient: true,
      _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
      _origins: '*:*',
      sockets: [Circular],
      eio: [Server],
      httpServer: [Server],
      engine: [Server]
    },
    sockets: [ [Socket] ],
    connected: { wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: [Socket] },
    fns: [],
    ids: 0,
    acks: {},
    adapter: [Circular]
  },
  rooms: {
    '-zzOKEUrvDOj_345AAAA': [],
    wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: [ wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: true ]
  },
  sids: { wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: { wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: true } },
  encoder: Encoder {}
}
{
  '-zzOKEUrvDOj_345AAAA': [],
  wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: [ wKTl5kLVfhWSTSt0AAAB: true ]
}
```

Can anyone provide any explanation or alternative method of doing this? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing your version of Socket-io but when the server is set up like:

```
let io = require('socket.io');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.join('Test');
    socket.join('Test1');
    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
});
```

And the client is set up like:

```
let io = require('socket.io-client');

socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8090")
```

The result that I get from the server on Nodejs v8.9.3 / Socket.io v2.2.0:

```
{
    c9kG4WD5hFlLUOZrAAAA: Room { sockets: { c9kG4WD5hFlLUOZrAAAA: true }, length: 1 },
    Test: Room { sockets: { c9kG4WD5hFlLUOZrAAAA: true }, length: 1 },
    Test2: Room { sockets: { c9kG4WD5hFlLUOZrAAAA: true }, length: 1 }
}
```

Digging through [Socket.IO documentation I found a reference to a method](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-join-room-callback) to show all of the rooms a socket is in and tested that:

```
let rooms = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
console.log(rooms);
```

Which returned:

```
[ 'c9kG4WD5hFlLUOZrAAAA', 'Test', 'Test2' ]
```

Which is an array of all the currently existing rooms by name only.

I sort of refined that with:

```
let roomName = rooms[rooms.length-1]; //Get last room pushed
console.log('A user joined the room with the name: ' + roomName + ". The user's name is X");
```

Which returned:

```
"A user joined the room with the name: Room 1. The user's name is X"
```

You could track the names of the rooms yourself in an array, but you would want to be careful as that could introduce a potential memory leak.

But if all you want is the very last room joined, you could just use whatever value as a var and pass that through the emit.

Comment: Hmm, this was an interesting read. Thanks for the details! Do you have any idea why my `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` is structured how it is?

Comment: I might have a better idea if I knew what version of Nodejs you were using.  You can run node -v to get that (if you didn't know, don't want to come off as pompous).

Comment: v8.12.0, just checked. Socket.IO version should be the latest.

Comment: Ha, don't know why I said nodejs, meant socket.io, doh.  I'll do some digging.

Comment: Hm, I ran it with 2.2.0 and it outputed the results above. I even ran it with your code precisely and it returned the same outputs. Could you run npm show socket.io version? Also, could you update your question with the results of console.log(io.sockets.adapter), maybe we can figure it out from that.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked and I'm running v2.2.0. Question updated too.

Comment: Now using Node.JS v12.4.0, by the way.

Comment: Missed this before, but what does `console.log(clients);` return?

For showing the user joined a room I would just pass the room name through.
For keeping track of users in a room I would let Socket.IO handle that.
For giving the user a list of the _sockets_ in the room, they don't need that.  The clients can't send client to client.

It's odd, but might be moot depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, When I logs this : ``` console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);``` It gives me output like this...
Map {
  'Ums2eRJrJU8hr8obAAAB' => Set { 'Ums2eRJrJU8hr8obAAAB' },
  '3a71a76c-3ae5-402e-8087-daeadad032c7' => Set { 'Ums2eRJrJU8hr8obAAAB' },
  'K7TaAz-FaXuiQrtpAAAD' => Set { 'K7TaAz-FaXuiQrtpAAAD' }
}. 
I didn't understand how to resolve this.
Also on logging the : let rooms = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
                                  console.log(rooms); 
output is [ ].